# Problema com "on change" seguido de "on click"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="esc" />
<input type="button" value="Ok" id="ok" />
```

E jquery/javascript:

```
$(document).on("change", "#esc", function(){
    alert("esc");
});

$(document).on("click", "#ok", function(){
    alert("ok");
});
```

Quando eu digito um texto numa textbox e clico direto no Ok ele não executa o codigo dentro da função do click. Somente o código da função do change.

Segue exmeplo no fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8389g5rj/1/

Qual o motivo disso e como posso resolver esse "conflito" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joao,

O que acontece é o seguinte.

Quando você altera o texto, liberando assim a trigger do change do textbox e tenta clicar no botão. O evento é disparado antes do click e o alert é chamado, fazendo então cancelar seu evento de click.

Se você mudar o código para o seguinte.

```
$(document).on("change", "#esc", function(){
    console.log("esc");
});

$(document).on("click", "#ok", function(){
    console.log("ok");
});
```

Você vai ver que os dois eventos são disparados normalmente. O problema do seu exemplo é o alert, que se torna preemptivo e impede que dispare o evento de click do botão, porque ele "passa na frente".

Deu para entender?

Para explicar melhor. O evento do seu botão é o "click" certo? Ele é disparado quando o usuário clica no botão. Porém no seu text input ele dispara o evento de change assim que você sai do text input, e por milissegundos (perspetivável para nós seres humanos) ele dispara o evento de change e dentro do evento de change chama o alert **ANTES** de você ter conseguido efetivamente clicado no botão. E quando o alert foi chamado "cancelou" seu click, por que na verdade você não conseguiu click no botão **Ok**.

Comment: Então se eu não tiver nenhum alert no meu código real esse problema não irá ocorrer? Não captei a definição de preemptivo

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Se você não tiver nada que "interrompa" o próximo evento. Por que o alert é chamado, ele depende de uma ação do usuário e ele é preemptivo, em outras palavras para o browser um alert é mais importante do o próximo evento (por exemplo). De maneira simples sem os alerts seus evento vão ser disparados de forma encadeada normalmente.

Comment: Interessante, não sabia desse tipo de comportamento!

Comment: Veja minha última edição onde eu tento explicar melhor.